# How to make specific areas in a div clickable with css / js / anything

Tags: html, jquery, css, events, jquery-events

I'd like to show you an image of my page content so you'd understand what am I talking about:

[image]

Now, I have two main divs on a page: the **wrapper (the red one)** and the **purple**:

```
<div id="purple" style="position:fixed; z-index:0; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%; filter:alpha(opacity=50); opacity:0.5; cursor:pointer;" onclick="javascript:alert('purple clicked');"></div>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

The **wrapper** contains many controls and other divs, and the **purple** is basically supposed to be clickable and perform some event, lets say `alert('purple clicked');`

The thing is that when I press inside the **wrapper** it also fires the **purple** event.
So what I did was to add the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#purple").click(function (e) 
    {            
        window.event.cancelBubble = true;            
        e.stopPropagation();
    })

</script>
```

I understood that through this code I'll manage to click on the purple area and get the alert fire, the problem is that when I click inside the red area this alert is fired also - and this is not what I wanted!

So, eventually, if you haven't given up yet reading this post, here's the question:

**How to avoid the "purple events" fire when clicking the red zone?**

p.s.
I must have the purple div be like - this can't be changed:

> width:100%; height:100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to prevent `bubbling down`. You have to use `event.target.id` to differentiate the `purple div` with others,

Try this,

```
$("#purple").click(function(e){
  if(e.target.id == "purple")
  {
       alert("purple clicked.!");
  } 
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7FBgb/1/)

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Although I used `event.target.nodeName` instead of `event.target.id` but the logic is the same. thank you

Answer (score 2):

This should solve your problem:

**CSS**

```
#wrapper
{
    z-index:1;
    margin: 0 -50px;
    left:50%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sa6cW/)

You have a problem because your purple div overlays the red one, the reason for that is:

> z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute,
>   position:relative, or position:fixed).

you should read more about it [Z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** Just realized your purple div does not encapsulate red/green divs. This answer won't solve your problem in that case. It relies on the nested div structure as per the included example below. I'll leave this answer in case someone else comes across it with a similar issue. [Maksym Stepanenko's answer below regarding `z-index`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20172864/1481489) is the most correct one.

---

There are two properties of the event object: `currentTarget` and `target`.

- `currentTarget` is the current element in the event bubbling phase.
- `target` is the element that is responsible for initiating the event.

Within the `purple` click event handler you could test to see if that element was the target in the event chain:

```
$('#purple').click(function(e) {
    if ( e.currentTarget == e.target ) {
        console.log('clicked purple',Date.now());
    }
});
$('#red').click(function(e) {
    console.log('clicked red',Date.now());
});
```

This is helpful when:

- you don't want to constrain the event phasing to only the red object
- you don't want to have to remember to put `e.stopPropagation` in every click handler whose element is a child of `#red`/`#purple`

Here's a complete working example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bubble Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #purple {border:3px solid #3c1e40;background:#b459bf;}
            #red {margin:auto;width:958px;border:3px solid #400Aa0a;background:#ff2829;}
            .green {margin:20px;padding:30px;border:3px solid #1c401c;background:#54bf55;}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#purple').click(function(e) {
                    if ( e.currentTarget == e.target ) {
                        console.log('clicked purple',Date.now());
                    }
                });
                $('#red').click(function(e) {
                    console.log('clicked red',Date.now());
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="purple">
            <div id="red">
                <p class="green">Hello World</p>
                <p class="green">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You could take this a step further and also compensate for `#red`:

```
$('#purple').click(function(e) {
    if ( e.currentTarget == e.target ) {
        console.log('clicked purple',Date.now());
    }
});
$('#red').click(function(e) {
    if ( e.currentTarget == e.target ) {
        console.log('clicked red',Date.now());
    }
});
$('.green').click(function(e) {
    console.log($(this).text(),Date.now());
});
```